# SQLCount distinct of one column based on another column

Tags: sql, oracle, session, count

I need to count the sessions which visited a particular page once and sessions which visited the same page once or more than once. For example: consider these sessions between 1st to 4th April:

```
Session_id| Date
----+---------
1| 01/04/2016
1| 02/04/2016
2| 01/04/2016
3| 01/04/2016
4| 01/04/2016
4| 03/04/2016
4| 04/04/2016
```

I can not do it using a sub query as there are millions of session. Hence a query like this won't work for me:

```
select case when no_of_visits=1 then 'single_visit'
            when no_of_visits>1 then 'multiple_visits' end as visit,
       count(distinct session_id) as sessions
FROM   (
  select session_id,
         count(distinct date) as no_of_visits
  from   my_table
  group by session_id
) a
group by case when no_of_visits=1 then 'single_visit'
              when no_of_visits>1 then 'multiple_visits' end
```

The answer should be like this:

```
Visit|Sessions
single_visit|2
multiple_visit|2
```

Is there any way where i can do something like this:
`count(distinct session_id) where no_of_visits=1 and count(distinct session_id) where no_of_visits>=1` without subquery or self join?
Any help would be deeply appreciated.

Comment: The answer you want is not clear. In the query you don't want to use you mention "single visit" and "multiple visits" - where is that in the output table you show under "The answer should be like this"?

Comment: Apologies for not making it clear. I just need to know the count of sessions that were accessed once and session that were accessed more than once.
The problem with using a sub query,having or a self join is that data is huge and hence these methods can't be used.

Comment: Why do you use `count(distinct date)`, do you need multiple visits on different dates? The 2nd `count(distinct  session_id)` is not needed as the session is already unique. And DISTINCT is quite expensive, when you get rid of it your subquery will perform fast (and there's no faster way to get the same result).

Comment: Yes, a session would only be considered to have multiple visits if the visits were occuring on different days. Hence the use of distinct dates. The second point i agree is valid. However, use of subquery still would be unsustainable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't avoid subqueries to get this result, but you can get rid of the `count(distinct)` (which is probably the most expensive part):

```
select no_of_visits,
       count(*) as sessions
FROM
 (
   select session_id,
          case when min(date) <> max(date) -- at least two different dates
               then 'multiple_visits'
               else 'single_visit'
          end  as no_of_visits
   from  table_name
   group by session_id
 ) a
group by no_of_visits
```

Answer (score 0):

It *seems* you want something like this:

```
select   session_id, count(distinct dt) as no_of_visits,
         case when count(distinct dt) = 1 then "Single visit" 
                                          else "Multiple visits" end as visit
from     my_table
group by session_id;
```

**Note**: I used dt rather than "date" as a column name; date is an Oracle key word, and such words should not be used as schema, table or column names.

Comment: Oh - so you just want to count how many single visits there were and how many multiple visits there were? and the output has just two rows?

Comment: Actually i want something like this:


select 'Single visit' as visits, count(distinct case when count(distinct date)=1 then session_id else NULL end)  as no_of_sessions


union


select 'Multiple visit' as visits, count(distinct case when count(distinct date)>1 then session_id else NULL end)  as no_of_sessions

Comment: I don't think you can do that in one pass, but selecting from the result of the query I wrote above shouldn't be too expensive. Please see dnoeth's note too - do you need "distinct" on dates within each session_id?

Answer (score 0):

**Oracle Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE table_name ( Session_id, "Date" ) AS
SELECT 1, DATE'2016-04-01' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1, DATE'2016-04-02' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, DATE'2016-04-01' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3, DATE'2016-04-01' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 4, DATE'2016-04-01' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 4, DATE'2016-04-03' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 4, DATE'2016-04-04' FROM DUAL;
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT visit,
       COUNT(1) AS Sessions
FROM   (
  SELECT session_id,
         CASE WHEN COUNT(1) > 1
              THEN 'Multiple Visits'
              ELSE 'Single Visit'
              END AS visit
  FROM   table_name
  GROUP BY session_id
)
GROUP BY visit;
```

**Output**:

```
VISIT             SESSIONS
--------------- ----------
Multiple Visits          2 
Single Visit             2
```

**Query 2**:

```
SELECT first_visit - multiple_visits AS single_visit,
       multiple_visits
FROM   (
  SELECT COUNT( CASE rn WHEN 1 THEN 1 END ) AS first_visit,
         COUNT( CASE rn WHEN 2 THEN 1 END ) AS multiple_visits
  FROM   (
    SELECT rn            --
    FROM   (             --
      SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY session_id ORDER BY ROWNUM ) AS rn
      FROM   table_name
    )                    --
    WHERE  rn <= 2       -- These lines are optional
  )
);
```

**Output**:

```
SINGLE_VISIT MULTIPLE_VISITS
------------ ---------------
           2               2
```